# Setting surface color based on atom index in py3Dmol

Tags: python

I want to set the surface color for my atoms of interest different than others. I know how to change colors by serial index in stick mode, but not surface.

I want something like this, but for surface:

```
i = my_index_of_interest
view.setStyle({'model': 0, 'serial': i}, {"stick": {'color': 'red'}})
```

I use `view.addSurface(py3Dmol.VDW, {'opacity': 0.5})` for showing the surface, but I'm not sure if there are other ways or not. Though the `serial` doens't work on this one.

(I hope someone creates a tag for py3Dmol)